# Elegant way to say - I'm just curious

Tags: american-english, british-english, slang

On the website we have two account types. One is car expert account and another is just a basic account. Website purpose is to have professionals share their experience with non professionals.

Accounts have different privileges. We assume that newly registered users don't lie to us. When user logins first time, we ask what type account is more suitable for him. Showing two buttons:

|I'm car expert| ---------- |I'm just curious|*

Is it good to have `I'm just curious` as an option for basic user account? Or maybe there are more elegant ways to describe `not a pro` account, without official language, and still be cool and not boring?:)

To make this question not opinion-based, could you please tell me what is correct to use in this situation. 
**Examples:**

*Please enlighten me*

*I'm looking for better insights* (is it correct to use plural?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is to use a [newcomer](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/newcomer). For example:

> I'm a car expert | ---------- | I'm a newcomer to cars

However, if you want to put an emphasis on curiosity, you can use [inquiring](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inquiring?topic=curiosity):

> ### inquiring
>
> adjective (UK also enquiring)
>
> (of someone's behaviour) always wanting to learn new things, or (of someone's expression) wanting to know something:
>
> - *You have a very inquiring mind, don't you?.*
> - *He gave her an inquiring look.*

And the usage would be:

> I'm a car expert | ---------- | I'm not an expert, but I have a very inquiring mind!

Also, as you write in one of the examples, *I'm looking for better insights* sounds correct (and using plural is fine), but in such choices it is better to offer a user two different ways that intersect very little or do not intersect at all - it is better to use antonyms or, if possible, context antonyms, to be precise, because a car expert might want to look for better insights too.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually I was partially wrong. Inquiring, [according to LDOCE Online](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/inquiring), goes only before a noun. So you might want to write *"I'm not an expert, but I have a very inquiring mind!"*. Here I dropped down *car* in *car expert* so that to use less words, which is appreciated in developing user interface. I'll edit the answer.